# How do I auto-bind properties in nested repeat-templates in polymer?

Tags: rest, firebase, polymer

I'm trying to make a simple extension of the table element. Where you can click a td, then it becomes editable, and when you edit the data it gets automatically persisted via a REST service.

[Here's what I got so far](http://jsbin.com/gapozoboto/2/edit)

As you can see, you can click the td's and edit them, but the data does not get persisted to the other side (which is firebase in this case). That's because the data in the td's aren't bound anymore to the data-property from which they came. Can somebody tell me how I can bind them to that property again? Or any other way I can persist the data to the correct row and key?

Comment: Just thinking... as far as I know contenteditable change events are not supported by polymer.
You could use the onkeys to update the model manually. this.$.data[key] = ...

Comment: Then I'm not sure how I can identify which td belongs to which data property. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know contenteditable change events are not supported by polymer. 
You could use the onkeys to update the model manually. 
In a on-* handler, you can access the named model instance using: e.target.templateInstance.model.:

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{user in users}}">
      <div on-click="{{clickHandler}}">{{user.name}}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-foo', {
      clickHandler: function(e, detail, sender) {
       console.log(sender.templateInstance.model.user.name);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sevesta told me that it could only be done manually, so I gave every td extra data-attributes so I could identify them and then at the stopEditing() function I update the models manually.

[See here.](http://jsbin.com/tesileluho/2/edit)